# I could not get the intended output from the written code

Tags: ruby

I have to write a method called `consonant_cancel` that takes in a sentence and returns a new sentence where every word begins with its first vowel. The intended output is for given test functions are:

- `puts consonant_cancel("down the rabbit hole") #=> "own e abbit ole"`
- `puts consonant_cancel("writing code is challenging") #=> "iting ode is allenging"`

But I am getting `"own e abbit it ole e"` and `"iting ing ode e is allenging enging ing"` with this code.

```rb
def consonant_cancel(sentence)
    arr = []
    vowels = 'aeiou'
    words = sentence.split

    words.each do |word|
        word.each_char.with_index do |char, i|
            if vowels.include?(char)
                arr << word[i..-1]
            end
        end
    end

    return arr.join(' ')
end

puts consonant_cancel("down the rabbit hole") #=> "own e abbit ole"
puts consonant_cancel("writing code is challenging") #=> "iting ode is allenging"
```

Can you guys help me to debug it?

Comment: _"iting ing ode e is allenging enging ing"_ – seems like you've written a pig latin variant by accident ;-)

Comment: Regular expressions were developed to answer questions such as yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we adding in a `puts` to see what's happening in your loop:

```rb
def consonant_cancel(sentence)
    arr = []
    vowels = 'aeiou'
    words = sentence.split
    words.each do |word|
        word.each_char.with_index do |char, i|
            if vowels.include?(char)
                puts char
                arr << word[i..-1]
            end
        end
    end
    return arr.join(' ')
end
```

Then running `consonant_cancel "hello world"` we see:

```
irb(main):044:0> consonant_cancel "hello world"
e
o
o
=> "ello o orld"
irb(main):045:0>
```

You'll see the same issue with any word with multiple consonants, because of the way you're looping over the characters in a word and checking for consonants.

An easier way to accomplish this would be with regular expressions.

```rb
words.split.map { |w| w.sub(/^[^aeiou]*/i, "") }.join(' ')
```

Comment: This regex solution produces output that is slightly off.

Comment: You're right. I had to change `/^[^aeiou]/i` to `/^[^aeiou]*/i`. Thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [String#gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) with a regular expression. There is no need to break the string into pieces for processing and subsequent recombining.

```
def consonant_cancel(str)
  str.gsub(/(?<![a-z])[a-z&&[^aeiou]]+/i,'')
end
```

```
consonant_cancel("down the rabbit hole")
  #=> "own e abbit ole"
consonant_cancel("writing code is challenging")
  #=> "iting ode is allenging"
```

See the section "Character Classes" in the doc for [Regexp](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Regexp.html) for an explanation of the `&&` operator.

We can write the regular expression in *free-spacing mode*<sup>1</sup> to make it self-documenting.

```
/
(?<!              # Begin a negative lookbehind
  [a-z]           # Match a lowercase letter
)                 # End negative lookbehind
[a-z&&[^aeiou]]+  # Match one or more lowercase letters other than vowels
/ix               # Invoke case-indifference and free-spacing modes
```

The negative lookahead ensures that no string of letters immediately preceded by a letter is matched. The line

```
[a-z&&[^aeiou]]+
```

can alternatively be written

```
[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]+
```

<sup>1. See the section "Free-Spacing Mode and Comments" in the doc for `Regexp`.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> word.each_char.with_index
> ```

This loop iterates all chars (and vowels) of the word. `break` it after the first vowel found, so it does not repeat the side-effects for subsequent vowels of this word.

---

As an alternative, here's another regex-based solution

```rb
def consonant_cancel(sentence)
  sentence.scan(/\b[^aeiou]*(.+?)\b/i).join(" ")
end
```

Comment: Well thank you for the solution but here ıi the question/ How can I break a do end loop in ruby.

Comment: @harderfasterstronger: have you tried searching for how to do this?

Comment: @harderfasterstronger Just use the keyword `break` after you append the string in `arr`.